# Функция pop для стека

Tags: c, стек

Предо мною стоит такая задача. Написать функцию `pop`, которая удаляет из стека последний (верхний) элемент.

Структура Stack

```
struct Stack 
{
    int value;
    struct Stack* next;
};
```

Пытался написать используя такой прототип: `void pop(Stack*  &head)`, но на C оказывается нельзя передавать ссылки. Я в указателях пока не сильно силен. Объясните, пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать данную программу.

Comment: Вместо ссылки на указатель используйте двойной указатель.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передать указатель на указатель:

```
void pop(Stack**head);
```

Примерно так:

```
Stack * head;
...
pop(&head);
```

Ну, а внутри функции работаете с `*head` так, как работали бы со ссылкой :)